# ssh localhost connection closed by 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ssh, connection, cygwin, localhost

So, I'm going through this tutorial ([Running Hadoop on windows using cygwin...](http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/#cygwin)) to setup hadoop on my WINDOWS (please don't ask why I would use Linux). So I got to this point that I need to SSH to my localhost and test the SSH using Cygwin, but it closes the connection and says:

Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

I've googled a lot but couldn't find any proper answer for my problem.

P.S.: I'm running cygwin on Windows 7 professional x64

any idea?

BTW, Here is a sample run:

```
 $ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 19:2d:f6:84:4d:e5:0d:d4:5e:e6:e5:a4:6a:3c:ea:8b
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Soroush/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Soroush/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you installed `Cygwin` and ran `ssh-host-config`, you might have created user `cyg_server`. So when you are connecting to `ssh`, you need to use the user `cyg_server@localhost`.

When you run ssh with that user, it will ask you for the password that you provided when you ran `ssh-host-config`.

```
$ ssh cyg_server@localhost
cyg_server@localhost's password:
Last login: Mon Dec 31 01:14:44 2012 from ::1
cyg_server@polorumpus ~
$
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: For some reason I am used to reboot in order to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the key isn't being accepted. Check that `/home/Soroush/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` has been added to `/home/Soroush/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I would also check that 
`RSAAuthentication yes` is set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Well, I added id_rsa.pub to the authorized_keys and I set RSAAuthentication to yes in sshd_config file, but still get the same result. I've written this code to add the key to authorized_keys: 
cd ~/.ssh \n
 
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

Comment: Remove the `\n` part. Do this: `cat ~/ssh/.id_rsa.pub > ~/ssh/.authorized_keys` That will overwrite the existing one with your rsa key and should work. `\n` is a typo in the document, and by the way - this isn't a programming problem :)

Comment: Ok, then check `/var/log/secure` for any mention of key problems. It could be the permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, make sure they are set to 600

Comment: Well, I don't have /var/log/secure . The only things I have under /var/log/ is these 4 files: lastlog, setup.log, setup.log.full, sshd.log

Comment: I also changed the mode of all files under ~/.ssh/ but still the same result

Comment: Then `tail -f /var/log/sshd.log` and try to ssh in again to see if there are any indications to what the problem is.

Comment: Did you get your problem get solved? I'm seeing the exact same problem while installing Hbase on Cygwin

Comment: Actually I re-installed cygwin and when I was installing Hadoop, I created a server user (unlike what all tutorials say that we don't have to create a server user) and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do these to fix the problem:

```
chown <USERNAME> /var/log/sshd.log
chown -R <USERNAME> /var/empty
chown <USERNAME> /etc/ssh*
chmod 755 /var/empty
chmod 644 /var/log/sshd.log
```

Note that the  is my desired user name, not cyg_server.

Answer (score 0):

I Found this post relating to my issue, but it turned out that my cyg_server account did not have administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was generated by Putty authentication agent (Pageant): it was running with a private key. For some reason, it tried to use it to connect to localhost. If I closed Pageant (or removed the key), I could ssh to localhost.
But as I wanted to have Pageant running (to be a client of other ssh servers), I managed to modify the local sshd service, so that it 'ignored' in some way Pageant, to accept connections:
Modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

PubkeyAuthentication no

Now, it works

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the 64-bit version of Cygwin to get this to work.